# How to use transform for different children of a grid cell to change size synchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

There are two elements in one grid cell, and when I use layout transform for the grid only the ink canvas is transformed and the image not changed at all . And when I use scaled transform instead of layout they both change but the problem is that it will overflow the scroll viewer.
C# :

```
private void editor_mouseWheel(Object sender , MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
   Matrix m = grid.LayoutTransform.Value;
   if (e.Delta > 0)
      grid.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1,1.1,0,0);
   else
      grid.ScaleAtPrepend(1/1.1,1/1.1,0,0);
   grid.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(m) ;
   grid.UpdateLayout();
}
```

And XAML :

```
<ScrollViewer>
 <Grid Name="grid" />
  <Image Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" />
  <InkCanvas Name="editor" Background="Transparent" />
 </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: i also tried scale and both wit and without center of scale point selection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LayoutTransform does actually affect the Image control. However, by default the Image control stretches its image to fit its bounds.

You may set the `Stretch` property to `None`:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Image Name="img" Stretch="None" />
    <InkCanvas Name="editor" Background="Transparent" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried everything , but it didn't work and by everything i means different structure not different properties , tnx a lot .